# Why does allMatch return true in case of empty list in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
boolean doAllMatch = strings.stream().allMatch(str -> str.startsWith("a"));
```

How funny is this. It is an empty list.
Still it says all match. Is this what we as developer really want ??

Comment: Certainly. _Everything_ in that list satisfy the condition. If you disagree, which element in that list doesn't satisfy the condition?

Comment: This is really a question about set theory, and set theory has certain standard rules about empty sets. One of these is that all "for-all" statements are true about an empty set.

Comment: You are seeing the [documented behavior](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)): “If the stream is empty then `true` is returned and the predicate is not evaluated.”

Answer (score 2):

Yes, generally.  That's how pretty much every definition of `all` in any language works -- it's *true* that all the elements match the condition.  There is no element that doesn't match the condition, after all.

Comment: Just a question of perspective :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth: the second example of a "vacuously true statement" is exactly applicable here.